# Converting Cartesian image to polar, appearance differences

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, mapping, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to do a polar transform on the first image below and end up with the second. However my result is the third image. I have a feeling it has to do with what location I choose as my "origin" but am unsure.

[image: Target Image]

[image: Goal]

[image: My Transform]

```
  radius = sqrt(width**2 + height**2)
  nheight = int(ceil(radius)/2)
  nwidth = int(ceil(radius/2))
 for y in range(0, height):
   for x in range(0, width):
     t =  int(atan(y/x))
     r = int(sqrt(x**2+y**2)/2)
     color = getColor(getPixel(pic, x, y))
     setColor( getPixel(radial,r,t), color)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few differences / errors:

1. They use the centre of the image as the origin
2. They scale the axis appropriately. In your example, you're plotting your angle (between 0 and in your case, pi), instead of utilising the full height of the image.
3. You're using the wrong atan function (atan2 works a lot better in this situation :))
4. Not amazingly important, but you're rounding unnecessarily quite a lot, which throws off accuracy a little and can slow things down.

This is the code combining my suggested improvements. It's not massively efficient, but it should hopefully work :)

```py
  maxradius = sqrt(width**2 + height**2)/2
  rscale = width / maxradius
  tscale = height / (2*math.pi)
  for y in range(0, height):
   dy = y - height/2
   for x in range(0, width):
     dx = x - width/2
     t =  atan2(dy,dx)%(2*math.pi)
     r = sqrt(dx**2+dy**2)
     color = getColor(getPixel(pic, x, y))
     setColor( getPixel(radial,int(r*rscale),int(t*tscale)), color)
```

In particular, it fixes the above problems in the following ways:

1. We use `dx = x - width / 2` as a measure of distance from the centre, and similarly with `dy`. We then use these in replace of `x`, `y` throughout the computation.
2. We will have our `r` satisfying `0 <= r <= sqrt( (width/2)^2 +(height/2)^2 )`, and our `t` eventually satisfying `0 < t <= 2 pi` so, I create the appropriate scale factors to put `r` and `t` along the `x` and `y` axes respectively.
3. Normal `atan` can only distinguish based on gradients, and is computationally unstable near vertical lines... Instead, `atan2` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) solves both problems, and accepts `(y,x)` pairs to give an angle. `atan2` returns an angle `-pi < t <= pi`, so we can find the remainder modulo `2 * math.pi` to it to get it in the range `0 < t <= 2pi` ready for scaling.
4. I've only rounded at the end, when the new pixels get set.

Any questions, just ask!

Comment: Glad it turned out to work.. BTW, I just realised the line where I created the `r` in the loop had an incorrect division by 2. I've fixed it now!

Comment: :D I did notice that. One other thing that I notice is that it seems there are missing pixels. Is this because of rounding or have they applied a second process to fill those?

Comment: Yeah, that'll be because the map is not 1-to-1... Some areas of the new image come from much smaller areas of the original image (so that'll particularly be true at the top of the new image, where the radius is small). Unfortunately, you'll have to fill those in in an after pass. 
A more simple solution is arguably to compute the inverse map... ie loop over t and r, and compute x = round(r cos(t)) + width/2 , y = round(r sin(t)) + height/2, and if these x and y's lie in the old image, we copy the value to the corresponding r* rscale, t* tscale position in the new image... If that makes sense?

Comment: Yes it absolutely does make sense.