# Log-polar transform

Tags: java, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to perform a Log-polar transform on an image for the purpose of image registration. In other words I'm trying to achieve this:

[image: Input image] ------> [image: output image (nevermind the red lines)]

I need to code this from scratch in Java because I'll be doing this on the GPU side with OpenCL Java bindings and can't use libraries. There are multiple threads on this but none that could really help me, mostly because they're all using in-built MATLAB functions that I cannot replicate.

I've been trying the Polar Transform instead of the Log-Polar Transform for the sake of getting this to work because most info online refers to the first. So far, the best result I've had is with this bit here (pseudocode), based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080577/converting-cartesian-image-to-polar-appearance-differences):

```
w = input.width; // Width of the input image
h = input.height; // Height of the input image

// Copy input pixels into an array
for(y=0; y<h; y++){
    for(x=0; x<w; x++){
        input[y*w+x] = getPixel(x, y);
    }
}

// Polar transform
maxRadius = sqrt(w*w + h*h);
radiusScale = w / maxRadius;
angleScale = h / (2 * PI);

for(y=0; y<h; y++){
    dy = y - h/2; // Distance from the center in the y-axis
    for(x=0; x<w; x++){
        dx = x - w/2; // Distance from the center in the x-axis
        angle = atan2(dy, dx) % (2*PI);
        radius = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
        newY = radius * radiusScale;
        newX = radius * thetaScale;
        output[y*w+x] = input[newY*w+newX];
    }
}
```

What I get resembles some sort of polar transformation, despite not being the result that I'm looking for:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCuHl.png)

Can someone give me any pointers on this?

Thanks

EDIT:
The log-polar transform goes like [image: this].

EDIT:
Implementing @matt suggestions I now have the following code:

```
    w = input.width; // Width of the input image
    h = input.height; // Height of the input image
    maxRadius = sqrt(w*w/4 + h*h/4);
    radiusScale = h / maxRadius;
    angleScale = w /PI/2;
    offset = PI;
    
    for(y=0; y<h; y++){
        dy = y - h/2; // Distance from center in the y-axis
        for(x=0; x<w; x++){
            dx = x - w/2; // Distance from the center in the x-axis
            angle = atan2(dy, dx);
            radius = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
            
            newY = radius * radiusScale;
            newX = (angle + offset) * angleScale;
            
            output[newY*w+newX] = input.getPixel(x, y); 
        }
    }
```

Plotting the new output gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3rs2.png), which is still not what I expect to get.

Comment: You know what would be helpful, the code you have to generate the images. A better description of the transform would help too. If it is a purely geometric transform, wouldn't there be an original pixel at x,y and then it would be placed in the new image at newX, newY?

Comment: If you mean the input images, I'm not generating them, I just use the one I shared because I have the corresponding expected output to compare my results to.
I've edited my post to include the description of the transform. Indeed I read it as a pixel remapping but I'm unable to get it to work...

Comment: No, I meant the actual code to generate the iamge. Eg. Load an image from a file, do your incorrect transform and save the image to a file. That way we could actually provide a complete compilable example.

Comment: I'm not doing that, I just have the image open in ImageJ and use the Macro language to run the code on it. I'll compile when I have it working though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue with this transform is that each "pixel" in the transformed space takes up a different amount of space in the x,y space. So here is how I am defining the transform.

- Our new image will have the same dimensions
- The Y axis will be 0 to Max Rho
- The X axis will be -PI to +PI

So we start by iterating over the i,j coordinates of the output image. The resulting rho and theta are as follows.

```
double rho = j*maxRho / height;
double theta = i*maxTheta / width + offset;
```

Now we need to grab the input pixels at the respective location.

```
int x = (int) ( Math.exp(rho)*Math.cos(theta) + width/2);
int y = (int) ( Math.exp(rho)*Math.sin(theta) + height/2);
```

Now we can get the pixel value.

```
int pixel = input[y*width + x];
```

*Your input variable is a bit redundante since you could just use your `getPixel(x, y)`*

Then we just set the corresponding output value.

```
output[j*width + i] = pixel;
```

Here is a compilable example.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
public class ScannerJunk{
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read( new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvDQT.png") );
        
        BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage( img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        
        double w = img.getWidth();
        double h = img.getHeight();
        
        double maxRho = 0.5*Math.log( w*w/4.0 + h*h/4.0 );
        
        double maxTheta = 2 * Math.PI;
        double offset = - Math.PI;
        for(int i = 0; i< w; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j< h; j++){
                double rho = j*maxRho / h;
                double theta = i*maxTheta / w + offset;
                int x = (int) ( Math.exp(rho)*Math.cos(theta) + w/2);
                int y = (int) ( Math.exp(rho)*Math.sin(theta) + h/2);
                
                try{
                    out.setRGB( i, j, img.getRGB( x, y ) );
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println( i + ", " + j + " :: " + rho + ", " + theta + " :: " + x + ", " + y );
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        ImageIO.write(out, "PNG", new File("transformed.png") );
  }
}
```

Note that the max radius, does not map to the input image for all of the possible angles.

Also, the radius and theta axis appeat to be transposed from your example image.

Comment: Thanks, we're getting somewhere but not quite there yet. I implemented your suggestions but I still don't get the expected result. I can't post an image as a comment so I'll update my post with it. Please check it.

Comment: Oops, I just saw your edit now, 1 sec. Thanks again

Comment: You took the square roots out on purpose or by mistake?
Also, I've now implemented your suggestions but am getting a negative index error (radius = -infinity AKA 0 < sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) < 1)

Comment: @AfonsoMendes I've updated the code, and made a compilable example. It has some issues, and Ill fix those.

Comment: I tried to edit my last comment but was unable to. The negative infinity comes from log(0) indeed. Let me check how people deal with this.

Comment: I've seen this approach elsewhere online but couldn't wrap my head around it. Let me try out your code and I'll be back. Once again, thank you very much

Comment: Your code seems to work like a charm, yet the resolution in the output differs from that of the expected output image. Do you think they are using some sort of interpolation to get that resolution?

Comment: @AfonsoMendes how are you creating the output? The version you showed appears to be a crop, so maybe they're using a more limited range for rho and theta. Also they're probably interpolating x,y when they sample, this one just using (int)x, (int)y. If it's from imagej it's all open source and you can look at what they're doing exactly.

Comment: I'm creating the output image in ImageJ macros with:

newImage("polar", "32-bit black", w, h, 1);
for(y=0; y<h; y++){
 for(x=0; x<w; x++){
  setPixel(x, y, output[y*w+x]);
 }
}

Also, you missed the sqrt() in the log(), can you update your answer?
The images I provided in the beginning are from https://sthoduka.github.io/imreg_fmt/docs/log-polar-transform/ which shows the pipeline I'm trying to implement.

Comment: Log( Sqrt( Z ) ) is equal to 1/2 Log( Z ) so I put the sqrt out front as a factor after you pointed it out the first time.

Comment: Ok sorry. But then your solution gives me negative indexes

Comment: Yes, because the range rho goes so far that there are values that are not on the origin image. If you want to remve those you have to limit the range of rho, you could use a maximum rho of Math.min( 0.5\*Math.log( w\*w/4), 0.5\*Math.log(h\*h/4.0) ); I used a maximum that goes to the corner of the original image. That only works for a very small set of angles.

Comment: What I did now and seems to match the results in the literature, is just skip the iterations where (x,y) falls outside the image, leaving those pixels as zero. That way you're also making sure you reach the corners and don't discard any information.
I can't thank you enough for your help!